# Longest positive subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Array A[] contains only '1' and '-1'

Construct array B, where B[i] is the length of the longest continuous subarray starting at j and ending at i, where `j < i and A[j] + .. + A[i] > 0`

Obvious O(n^2) solution would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
    j = i-1;
    sum = A[i];
    B[i] = -1; //index which fills criteria not found
    while ( j >=0 ) {
        sum += A[j];
        if (sum > 0)
            B[i] = i - j + 1;
        --j;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for O(n) solution.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the algorithm, not an implementation in C++?

Comment: @Phil Moesch Yeah...can you be more specific?

Comment: @Vaughn Cato Updated

Comment: Does the subsequence need to be continuous?

Comment: @PhamTrung https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence by definition is not required to be continuous. Looks like that's NOT what the OP means and someone should edit his post to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Pham Trung Yes it has to be continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to realize that we only need to find the minimum j such that `(A[0] + ... + A[j-1]) == (A[0] + ... + A[i]) - 1`.  `A[j] + ... + A[i]` is the the same as `(A[0] + ... + A[i]) - (A[0] + ... + A[j-1])`, so once we find the proper j, the sum between j and i is going to be 1.
Any earlier j wouldn't produce a positive value, and any later j wouldn't give us the longest possible sequence.  If we keep track of where we first reach each successive negative value, then we can easily look up the proper j for any given i.

Here is a C++ implementation:

```cpp
vector<int> solve(const vector<int> &A)
{
    int n = A.size();
    int sum = 0;
    int min = 0;
    vector<int> low_points;
    low_points.push_back(-1);
    // low_points[0] is the position where we first reached a sum of 0
    // which is just before the first index.
    vector<int> B(n,-1);
    for (int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
        sum += A[i];
        if (sum<min) {
            min = sum;
            low_points.push_back(i);
            // low_points[-sum] will be the index where the sum was first
            // reached.
        }
        else if (sum>min) {
            // Go back to where the sum was one less than what it is now,
            // or go all the way back to the beginning if the sum is
            // positive.
            int index = sum<1 ? -(sum-1) : 0;
            int length = i-low_points[index];
            if (length>1) {
                B[i] = length;
            }
        }
    }
    return B;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the sum of +1/-1, like on my graph. We start at 0 (it doesnt matter).

[image: representation of sums of +1/-1]

So: you want, when considering anything point, to get the **at left** other point which is **most far**, and **below it**.

**1 construct and keep the sum**

It takes n iterations : O(n)

**2 construct a table value=>point, iterating every point, and keeping the most at left:**

You get: 0 => a, 1 => b (not d), 2 => c (not e,i,k), 3 => f (not h), 4 => g (not m), 5 => n, 6 => o

It takes n iterations : O(n)

**3 at each level (say 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) => you keep the point most far, which is below it:**

level 0 => a

level 1 => a

etc. => it will be always a.

Suppose graph begins at point g:

4 => g

3 => h

2 => i

5 => g

6 => g

Then: if a point is just over 3 (then 4: as m) => it will be h

It takes also n operations at max (height of the graph precisely).

**4 iterate each point: your B[i].**

At each point, say h : sum = 3, you take the most far below it (table of operation 3): in my schema it is always a = 0;

Suppose graph begins at point g:

for points

g, h, i, k => nothing

j => i

l => i

m => h

n => g

**You can combine some operations in the same iteration.**