# Find the longest subarray that contains a majority element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve this algorithmic problem:

https://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/469/

For convenience, I have summarized the problem  statement below.

> Given an array of length (<= 2,000,000) containing integers in the range [0, 1,000,000], find the
>   longest **subarray** that contains a majority element.
>
> A majority element is defined as an element that occurs > floor(n/2) times in a list of length n.
>
> Time limit: 1.5s
>
> For example:
>
> If the given array is [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2],
>
> The answer is 5 because the subarray [2, 1, 2, 3, 2] of length 5 from position 1 to 5 (0-indexed) has the number 2 which appears 3 > floor(5/2) times. Note that we cannot take the entire array because 3 = floor(6/2).

---

**My attempt:**

The first thing that comes to mind is an obvious brute force (but correct) solution which fixes the start and end indexes of a subarray and loop through it to check if it contains a majority element. Then we take the length of the longest subarray that contains a majority element. This works in O(n^2) with a small optimization. Clearly, this will not pass the time limit.

I was also thinking of dividing the elements into buckets that contain their indexes in sorted order.

Using the example above, these buckets would be:

1: 0,  2

2: 1, 3, 5

3: 4

Then for each bucket, I would make an attempt to merge the indexes together to find the longest subarray that contains k as the majority element where k is the integer label of that bucket.
We could then take the maximum length over all values of k. I didn't try out this solution as I didn't know how to perform the merging step.

---

Could someone please advise me on a better approach to solve this problem?

**Edit:**

I solved this problem thanks to the answers of PhamTrung and hk6279. Although I accepted the answer from PhamTrung because he first suggested the idea, I **highly recommend** looking at the answer by hk6279 because his answer elaborates the idea of PhamTrung and is much more detailed (and also comes with a nice formal proof!).

Comment: Your dividing the indexes into buckets is a good idea and leads to an O(N) algorithm

Comment: @Matt Timmermans How so?

Comment: Yeah... it's a complicated answer that I don't have time to write right now, but in way of a hint:  From an index list you can calculate the list of cumulative counts of matching elements preceding each index.  From two adjacent elements in that list, you can easily calculate the cumulative match-mismatch at all intermediate indexes.  For each index, the longest subarray ending at that index that mas a majority of matching elements starts at the smallest index with a smaller cumulative match-mismatch count.

Comment: @MattTimmermans what you commented above makes sense - "For each index, the longest subarray ending at that index that has a majority of matching elements starts at the smallest index with a smaller cumulative match-mismatch count." (I think that's what Pham Trung's answer also suggests.) To make the overall algorithm O(n), though, as you stated, it seems we'd need to find that smallest index in O(1). What was your idea to accomplish that?

Comment: @גלעדברקן as you progress through the index list, you track the match-mismatch value.  Add it with the index to the end of a list when you encounter one that is lower then all previous values. The values in the list will decrease monotonically. 
 When you're not adding new values you are looking for your current value in the list.  You could do a binary search, but because the value you're looking for changes very slowly, it's faster just walk up or down in the list to track the desired position as it chagnes.  That takes O(1) amortized time per item in the list.

Comment: @MattTimmermans ah, right. For any `k` occurrences going up, while tracking back in the list in O(1), if we jump down, we can add at most `k` iterations, tracking back down the list. So it seems we'd be bound by around `2 * num_occurences` in total per character. Nice. (In my answer, I suggested hashing while going up, but your suggestion could possibly be faster in practice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: attempt 1 is wrong as @hk6279 has given a counter example. Thanks for pointing it out.

**Attempt 1:** 
The answer is quite complex, so I will discuss a brief idea

Let process each unique number one by one.

Processing each occurrence of number `x` from left to right, at index `i`, let add an segment `(i, i)` indicates the start and end of the current subarray. After that, we need to look to the left side of this segment, and try to merge the left neighbour of this segment into `(i, i)`, (So, if the left is `(st, ed)`, we try to make it become `(st, i)` if it satisfy the condition) if possible, and continue to merge them until we are not able to merge, or there is no left neighbour.

We keep all those segments in a stack for faster look up/add/remove.

Finally, for each segment, we try to enlarge them as large as possible, and keep the biggest result.

Time complexity should be `O(n)` as each element could only be merged once.

**Attempt 2**:

Let process each unique number one by one

For each unique number `x`, we maintain an array of counter. From 0 to end of the array, if we encounter a value `x` we increase the count, and if we don't we decrease, so for this array
[0,1,2,0,0,3,4,5,0,0] and number `0`, we have this array counter

[1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0]

So, in order to make a valid subarray which ends at a specific index `i`, the value of `counter[i] - counter[start - 1]` must be greater than 0 (This can be easily explained if you view the array as making from 1 and -1 entries; with `1 is when there is an occurrence of x, -1 otherwise`; and the problem can be converted into finding the subarray with sum is positive)

So, with the help of a binary search, the above algo still have an complexity of O(n ^ 2 log n) (in case we have n/2 unique numbers, we need to do the above process n/2 times, each time take O (n log n))

To improve it, we make an observation that, we actually don't need to store all values for all counter, but just the values of counter of `x`, we saw that we can store for above array counter:

[1,#,#,0,1,#,#,#,-1,0]

This will leads to O (n log n) solution, which only go through each element once.

Comment: What is your criteria for merge? I had a similar idea but couldn't make out when to merge 2 segments.

Comment: @LanceHAOH as we have the start and end of the segment, we can calculate the length of the segment. And together with the number of occurrence of `x` inside the segment, we can decide.

Comment: @LanceHAOH For example, if we add (4,4) and the left is (0,2) with 2 occurrence, so the total length is 5 and total occurrence is 3, so we can merge them. But if we add (5,5) and the left is (0,2), we can not merge. But if there is (6,6) followed, we can merge (6,6) and (5,5) then (5,6) to (0,2)

Comment: Let's say that we have 2 segments x, y and z such that x occurs first (in a left-to-right order) followed by y then z. y is greater than the "reach" of x. But y can be merged with z to form segment yz. As a result, segment yz can now be merged with segment x. How does your algorithm take care of this case?

Comment: @LanceHAOH you need to continue to merge until none can be merged as stated in the answer. However, as the number of merge can happen at most twice for each element (one time to merge its left neighbour, and one to merge its right neighbour), so the time complexity should still be O(n log n) - 2*n merges and each look up is O( log n )

Comment: Alright. Your solution looks promising. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @LanceHAOH I just realise that binary search tree is unnecessary, and we just need a deque or stack to get the latest segment, so time complexity should just be O (n)

Comment: If we have 3 segments x,y and z in left-to-right order such that xy and yz can merge, but xyz cannot. And yz is the longest subarray. What will this algorithm return? (A sample : [0,1,2,0,0,3,4,5,0,0])

Comment: @hk6279 Just found another solutions. Should be correct this time.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Updated with another solutions

Comment: @PhamTrung Even if we find an index start-1 < i such that counter[i] - counter[start-1] > 0, how would we know that this is a candidate longest subarray? There could be an index j < start such that counter[i] - counter[j-1] > 0 and i - j + 1 > i - start + 1.

Comment: @LanceHAOH Do you know the problem [Longest positive subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701919/longest-positive-subarray) This can be solved similar with a little tweak.

Comment: @PhamTrung While thinking of the implementation details, I thought of a potential problem. We will need to transform our array of n elements into 1 and -1 each time we process a distinct element. That means that this algorithm would be in O(n^2). Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @LanceHAOH as stated in the answer you only needs to care about +1 entries, (we can always know the correct result of the `counter` array if you calculate them based on their distances with the last +1 entry), which mean you can make assumption that the subarray can start and end with same values `x`, and then, from those positions, you can adjust accordingly. This problem is hard and it is tricky to get O (n log n) implementation.

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, this solution should be correct. When there exist two counter of same value for a particular `x` with index position i and 2k+i, there must be exactly k+1 number of `x` and the array length is 2k+1

Comment: @hk6279 We should maintain a decreasing queue, which means if the `counter` is [1,#,#,0,1,#,#,#,-1,0] for example, we only store [1,0,-1] and not [1,0,1,-1,0] because we need the longest sub array. Then, applying binary search into this decreasing queue. Or store them in a binary search tree is also ok.

Comment: I think linear-time algorithm is possible. [This paper (section 3)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjF-KqV-tzYAhWJ3iwKHbtQAUEQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.csie.ntu.edu.tw%2F~kmchao%2Fpapers%2F2005_IPL_Longest.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2KBvGD0zsfL9pnXOeD4TGf) suggests a simple dynamic programming approach.

Comment: (In case it might interest you, if I'm not mistaken, a way to make it O(n) might be found in my answer. Does it make sense?)

Answer (score 2):

This elaborate and explain how attempt 2 in @PhamTrung solution is working

---

To get the length of longest subarray. We should

1. Find the max. number of majority element in a valid array, denote as `m`

   - This is done by attempt 2 in @PhamTrung solution
2. Return min( 2*`m`-1, length of given array)

---

**Concept**

The attempt is stem from [a method to solve longest positive subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722012/3759505)

We maintain an array of counter for each unique number `x`. We do a `+1` when we encounter `x`. Otherwise, do a `-1`.

Take array [0,1,2,0,0,3,4,5,0,0,1,0] and unique number `0`, we have array counter [1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,-1,0]. If we blind those are not target unique number, we get [1,#,#,0,1,#,#,#,-1,0,#,0].

We can get valid array from the blinded counter array when there exist two counter such that the value of the right counter is greater than or equal to the left one. See Proof part.

To further improve it, we can ignore all # as they are useless and we get [1(0),0(3),1(4),-1(8),0(9),0(11)] in count(index) format.

We can further improve this by not record counter that is greater than its previous effective counter. Take counter of index 8,9 as an example, if you can form subarray with index 9, then you must be able to form subarray with index 8. So, we only need [1(0),0(3),-1(8)] for computation.

You can form valid subarray with current index with all previous index using binary search on counter array by looking for closest value that is less than or equal to current counter value (if found)

---

**Proof**

When right counter greater than left counter by `r` for a particular x, where k,r >=0 , there must be **k+r** number of `x` and **k** number of non `x` exist after left counter. Thus

1. The two counter is at index position i and r+2k+i
2. The subarray form between [i, r+2k+i] has exactly **k+r+1** number of `x`
3. The subarray length is **2k+r+1**
4. The subarray is valid as (**2k+r+1**) <= 2 * (**k+r+1**) -1

---

**Procedure**

1. Let `m` = 1
2. Loop the array from left to right
3. For each index p<sub>i</sub>

   - If the number is first encounter,

     > 1. **Create a new counter array** [1(p<sub>i</sub>)]
     > 2. **Create a new index record** storing current index value (p<sub>i</sub>) and counter value (1)
   - Otherwise, reuse the counter array and index array of the number and perform

     > 1. **Calculate current counter value c<sub>i</sub>** by c<sub>prev</sub>+2-(p<sub>i</sub> - p<sub>prev</sub>), where c<sub>prev</sub>,p<sub>prev</sub> are counter value and index value in index record
     > 2. **Perform binary search** to find the longest subarray that can be formed with current index position and all previous index position. **i.e. Find the closest c, c<sub>closest</sub>, in counter array where c<=c<sub>i</sub>**. If not found, jump to step 5
     > 3. **Calculate number of `x`** in the subarray found in step 2
     >
     >    r = c<sub>i</sub> - c<sub>closest</sub>
     >
     >    k = (p<sub>i</sub>-p<sub>closest</sub>-r)/2
     >
     >    number of `x` = k+r+1
     > 4. **Update counter `m`** by number of `x` if subarray has number of `x` > m
     > 5. **Update counter array** by append current counter if counter value less than last recorded counter value
     > 6. **Update index record** by current index (p<sub>i</sub>) and counter value (c<sub>i</sub>)

Comment: If we ignore the #, how would we solve this case: [3, 3, 1]? Using your algorithm, we will only see [3, 3] right?

Comment: My bad. I just saw the header "Find the max. number of majority element in a valid array...". In that case, your method is correct. Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! I'll give it a try. If I am not wrong, your method has O(nlogn) time complexity. Is there any trick that will make it O(n)?

Comment: @LanceHAOH This algorithm is exactly same as PhamTrung's attempt 2, so it will have O(nlogn) time complexity and O(n) space complexity. Any trick to make it O(n)? I can't think of any method to remove the binary search to reduce the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending so much time to help me! I implemented this solution and got AC! But since PhamTrung first suggested this idea, I will mark his answer as accepted but I will mention both of your answers as the recommended answers in my edited question post.

Comment: (In case it might interest you, if I'm not mistaken, a "trick to make it O(n)" might be found in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's an outline of an `O(n)` theory. Consider the following, where `*` are characters different from `c`:

```
    * c * * c * * c c c
 i: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

A plot for adding `1` for `c` and subtracting `1` for a character other than `c` could look like:

```
  sum_sequence

  0    c               c
 -1  *   *   c       c
 -2        *   *   c
 -3              *
```

A plot for the minimum of the above sum sequence, seen for `c`, could look like:

```
  min_sum

  0    c * *
 -1  *       c * *
 -2                c c c
```

Clearly, for each occurrence of `c`, we are looking for the leftmost occurrence of `c` with `sum_sequence` lower than or equal to the current `sum_sequence`. A non-negative difference would mean `c` is a majority, and leftmost guarantees the interval is the longest up to our position. (We can extrapolate a maximal length that is bounded by characters other than `c` from the inner bounds of `c` as the former can be flexible without affecting the majority.)

Observe that from one occurrence of `c` to the next, its `sum_sequence` can decrease by an arbitrary size. However, it can only ever increase by `1` between two consecutive occurrences of `c`. Rather than each value of `min_sum` for `c`, we can record linear segments, marked by `c`s occurrences. A visual example:

```
[start_min
    \
     \
      \
       \
      end_min, start_min
                  \
                   \
                   end_min]
```

We iterate over occurrences of `c` and maintain a pointer to the optimal segment of `min_sum`. Clearly we can derive the next `sum_sequence` value for `c` from the previous one since it is exactly diminished by the number of characters in between.

An increase in `sum_sequence` for `c` corresponds with a shift of `1` back or no change in the pointer to the optimal `min_sum` segment. If there is no change in the pointer, we hash the current `sum_sequence` value as a key to the current pointer value. There can be `O(num_occurrences_of_c)` such hash keys.

With an arbitrary decrease in `c`'s `sum_sequence` value, either (1) `sum_sequence` is lower than the lowest `min_sum` segment recorded so we add a new, lower segment and update the pointer, or (2) we've seen this exact `sum_sequence` value before (since all increases are by `1` only) and can use our hash to retrieve the optimal `min_sum` segment in `O(1)`.

As Matt Timmermans pointed out in the question comments, if we were just to continually update the pointer to the optimal `min_sum` by iterating over the list, we would still only perform `O(1)` amortized-time iterations per character occurrence. We see that for each increasing segment of `sum_sequence`, we can update the pointer in `O(1)`. If we used binary search only for the descents, we would add at most `(log k)` iterations for every `k` occurences (this assumes we jump down all the way), which keeps our overall time at `O(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

**Algorithm** :
Essentially, what Boyer-Moore does is look for a suffix sufsuf of nums where suf[0]suf[0] is the majority element in that suffix. To do this, we maintain a count, which is incremented whenever we see an instance of our current candidate for majority element and decremented whenever we see anything else. Whenever count equals 0, we effectively forget about everything in nums up to the current index and consider the current number as the candidate for majority element. It is not immediately obvious why we can get away with forgetting prefixes of nums - consider the following examples (pipes are inserted to separate runs of nonzero count).

[7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 1 | 5, 7 | 5, 5, 7, 7 | 7, 7, 7, 7]

Here, the 7 at index 0 is selected to be the first candidate for majority element. count will eventually reach 0 after index 5 is processed, so the 5 at index 6 will be the next candidate. In this case, 7 is the true majority element, so by disregarding this prefix, we are ignoring an equal number of majority and minority elements - therefore, 7 will still be the majority element in the suffix formed by throwing away the first prefix.

[7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 1 | 5, 7 | 5, 5, 7, 7 | 5, 5, 5, 5]

Now, the majority element is 5 (we changed the last run of the array from 7s to 5s), but our first candidate is still 7. In this case, our candidate is not the true majority element, but we still cannot discard more majority elements than minority elements (this would imply that count could reach -1 before we reassign candidate, which is obviously false).

Therefore, given that it is impossible (in both cases) to discard more majority elements than minority elements, we are safe in discarding the prefix and attempting to recursively solve the majority element problem for the suffix. Eventually, a suffix will be found for which count does not hit 0, and the majority element of that suffix will necessarily be the same as the majority element of the overall array.

Here's Java Solution :

- Time complexity : O(n)
- Space complexity : O(1)

  ```
  public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
      int count = 0;
      Integer candidate = null;

      for (int num : nums) {
          if (count == 0) {
              candidate = num;
          }
          count += (num == candidate) ? 1 : -1;
      }

      return candidate;
  }
  ```

Comment: This is to find the `majorityElement`, not the answer for this question.